# Set Select Value and Update it with jQuery

Tags: jquery, select, load

I am trying to use a select box

```
<select id="box">
   <option>1</option>
   <option>2</option>
</select>
```

and firstly get it's value and then update this value when it changes ?

i.e.

```
var onLoadValue = $('#box').val();

$('#box').live('change', function () {
    onLoadValue = $(this).val();
});
```

This doesn't seem to be working however ? Can anyone assist ?

Comment: Are you setting "onLoadValue" inline or using .ready()?

Comment: I am rather confused as to what you're trying to do here...

Comment: @Andrew Hi - just grab a value from a select box OnLoad and update that `var` when it changes

@Diodeus - on .ready

Comment: @Tom Thanks for clearing that up!

Comment: @Tom - The chances are that the DOM isn't ready at the time your code runs. Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/interdream/z57LX/1/

Comment: @james - thanks for the response :) But I can't seem to update the value using your example ? i.e. using console.log() does update the val ? http://jsfiddle.net/z57LX/5/

Comment: @Tom - It does update, but the `console.log` line will only run once (in the `load` function). See this update: http://jsfiddle.net/interdream/z57LX/6/

Comment: @james thanks! :) update the answer and I'll select you :)

Answer (score 0):

Because a `<select>`s value is not determined by it's `value` proprty, it is determined by the `:selected` `<option>` element.

```
var onLoadValue = $("#box option:selected").text();
$('#box').live('change', function () {
    onLoadValue = $("option:selected", this).text();
});
```

This should work for you.